# Updatable/changable polygon vectors

Tags: andengine

Build - GLES2 Anchor-Center:
I'm having trouble, without myself getting into shaders, trying to draw simple polygons that once created can have their vector points changed. Do i have to destroy and recreate every time i want to change them?
I have been trying to use a small workaround with crocoware/orabig [StretchSprite](https://github.com/Orabig/AndEngineSpriteStretch), but i get pretty horrible texture bleeding and i have to use a texture.

#### Update:

I edited the HighPerformanceMeshVertexBufferObject by removing the final clause on mBufferData and adding a public function:

```
public void setBufferData(float[] pBufferData){
    this.mBufferData = pBufferData;
    this.setDirtyOnHardware();
}
```

and i can update it by using this line

```
((HighPerformanceMeshVertexBufferObject)tempMesh.getVertexBufferObject()).setBufferData(tempBufferData);
```

Is there any setback by using this method? Or why it's final and not editable to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had thought at the time, that the Final on bufferData made the fields inside the array final as well.

To update the Vectors on a Mesh or Shape etc. use this
Final Float tempBufferData = tempMesh.getBufferData();

edit the vertices and then set the hardware to dirty to update on the next frame.
mesh.getVertexBufferObject.setDirtyOnHardware();